# How can i revert the animate function's animation

Tags: jquery

here's a simple example of what i'm trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/ty5dtpd8/

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    $('#box1').animate({left: '+=300'}, 300);
    $('#box2').animate({top: '-=200', left: '-=100'}, 300);
    $('#box3').animate({left: '+=600'}, 300);    
});
```

when the button is pressed the boxes move.
my question is: how can i make them revert back to their previous position with a click, and without having to animated them all over again with the opposite values?

Comment: yes, but without having to add opposite values to each and every box.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/rxtLht7p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this using **[Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**

```js
var i = true;

$(':button').click(function() {
  $('#box1').animate({
    left: (i ? '+' : '-') + '=300'
  }, 300);
  $('#box2').animate({
    top: (i ? '-' : '+') + '=200',
    left: '-=100'
  }, 300);
  $('#box3').animate({
    left: (i ? '+' : '-') + '=600'
  }, 300);
  i = !i;
});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#box1 {
  background: green;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
#box2 {
  background: blue;
  top: 450px;
  left: 350px;
}
#box3 {
  background: red;
  top: 350px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
<input type="button" value="click me"></input>
```

Comment: thanks man, very helpful! how does this part work? (i ? '-' : '+') is it (i (if true :if false) '-' : '+')?

Comment: check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator